# ¿Cómo puedo desarrollar una sentencia SQL para crear una vista y ordenar los registros en orden descendente por su registro precio?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Estoy realizando un curso independiente de SQL/PHP y estoy atascado con un ejercicio. Para una tabla llamada Móviles tengo que desarrollar una sentencia SQL con la que crear una vista llamada ModelosAntiguos en la que se muestren el código del producto, su nombre y el precio de los registros y deben ordenarse por precio de manera descendente. He estado intentando averiguarlo por mi cuenta pero no encuentro la manera. Gracias.

Cito el ejercicio: "Para la tabla Móviles de la BBDD TiendaElectrónica, desarrolla una sentencia SQL con la que crear una vista llamada ModelosAntiguos en la que se muestren el código del producto, su nombre y el precio de los registros, ordenándose por Precio en orden descendente"

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se entiende tu problema? no sabes como crear una vista? no sabes hacer el sql? que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Necesitas cear una vista en SQL o necesitas hacer una consulta en SQL y mostrarla en una vista de php?

Comment: Disculpar si el titulo de la pregunta no es suficientemente explicativa, añadí toda la información en la descripción porque no quería poner un titulo de pregunta excesivamente extenso. Como explicaba, es una pregunta de un curso de MySQL, os pongo la pregunta literalmente del ejercicio:
"Para la tabla Móviles de la BBDD TiendaElectrónica, desarrolla una sentencia SQL con la que crear una vista llamada ModelosAntiguos en la que se muestren el código del producto, su nombre y el precio de los registros, ordenándose por Precio en orden descendente".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, creo que podría ser algo así:

```
SELECT codigoProducto, nombre, precio 
FROM Moviles
ORDER BY precio DESC;
```

El nombre variará según el nombre que les hayas dado en tu tabla.

Un saludo y bienvenido

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, si no estas seguro de lo que el OP necesita se puede preguntar y ayudarle a mejorar su pregunta, saludos.